# Orbeon Form Builder: load initial value from web service

Tags: orbeon

We are using Orbeon CE 4.7 and would like to display the result of a web service in a form field using the "Initial Value" formula. We control the web service, so it can return data in whatever format is needed (today, it's XML).

Is there a way we can do this in Form Builder/Form Runner, and if so, what would the syntax be?

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done by defining an [HTTP service in Form Builder](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/http-services.html) for web service that returns the data you want to show in the field, and then defining an [action in Form Builder](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/actions.html) that calls the service on form load, and uses the result to populate the field in question. However, this is a [PE-only feature](http://www.orbeon.com/pricing).

If you really can't use Orbeon Forms PE, since Orbeon Forms uses Saxon to run XPath, you could as a calculated value write XPath that uses [Saxon's ability to call Java code from XPath](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensibility/functions/staticmethods.html), and in your own Java code call the service. This somewhat cumbersome, as you can't do this directly from Form Builder, need to write Java code, build it, and add it the Orbeon Forms war.